# How can I get ssh-agent working over ssh and in tmux (on OS X)?

Tags: macos, ssh, tmux, ssh-agent

I have a private key set up for my github account, the passphrase to which is, I believe, stored in OS X's keychain. I certainly don't have to type it in when I open a terminal window and enter `ssh git@github.com`.

However, when I'm running bash over an ssh session, or locally inside a tmux session, I have to type in the passphrase every single time I attempt to ssh to github.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/158788/ssh-agent-and-screen) suggests that a similar problem exists with screen, but I don't really understand the issue well enough to fix it in tmux. There's also [this page](http://justinchouinard.com/blog/category/tmux/) which includes a fairly complicated solution, but for zsh.

**EDIT**:

In response to [@Mikel's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/237822/how-can-i-get-ssh-agent-working-in-tmux-on-os-x/237832#237832), from a local terminal I get the following output:

```
[~]
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/launch-S4HBD6/Listeners
[~] 
$ ssh-add -l
2048 [my key fingerprint] /Users/richie/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
[~]
$ typeset -p SSH_AUTH_SOCK
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/launch-S4HBD6/Listeners"
```

Whereas over ssh or in tmux I get:

```
[~]
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[~]
$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
[~]
$ typeset -p SSH_AUTH_SOCK
bash: typeset: SSH_AUTH_SOCK: not found
```

`echo $SSH_AGENT_PID` returns nothing whatever shell I run it from.

Comment: What about `typeset -p SSH_AUTH_SOCK`?

Comment: @Mikel `bash: typeset: SSH_AUTH_SOCK: not found` from within ssh/tmux. I'll try it locally tonight, if necessary.

Comment: @Mikel I've added that command's output to the question.

Comment: AFAIK, question and answers are not OS X-specific.
That's relevant to avoid some non-OS X-specific dups, namely http://superuser.com/q/334975/46794 and http://superuser.com/q/479796/46794.

Comment: @Blaisorblade I was under the impression my passphrase was stored in the OS X keychain (Although I can't remember now why I believed that to be the case). Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Rich: true, but that's orthogonal. Everything applies also to Linux and OS X system where the password is not stored in the keychain, with only one exception. The exception is that usually, you'd have to call ssh-add to type the passphrase and load it into the ssh-agent daemon, and it'd last *until reboot*, while your setup avoids that (see  https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases for details). I didn't know about that possibility!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My colleague created some bash functions to assist with finding a live agent: https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent

He uses it mainly for connecting between systems (laptop to desktop, etc), but I use it most often for local tmux sessions where you logout/in from your window manager (OS X for myself).

**Usage**

1. Download ssh-find-agent.bash (`git clone git://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent.git` works).
2. Add the following to ~/.bashrc:

   ```
   . /path/to/ssh-find-agent.bash
   ```
3. Then you can type the following to set SSH_AUTH_SOCK in your current shell:

   ```
   set_ssh_agent_socket
   ```

Comment: I accepted this answer rather than any of the others that might work because it *doesn't* required SSH agent forwarding, which is better for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

An elegant solution, picked up [from dagit.o](http://blog.codersbase.com/2012/03/tmux-ssh-agent.html):

Create `~/.ssh/rc`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -S "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    ln -sf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
fi
```

Add to `~/.tmux.conf`

```
set -g update-environment "DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"
set-environment -g 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK' ~/.ssh/ssh_auth_sock
```

Answer (score 7):

In your `.tmux.conf` configuration file, add this line:

> set -g update-environment "SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION"

This causes these environment variables to be copied from your main shell to any shells opened within tmux, which then allows ssh-agent to work properly within those tmux shells.

Comment: This is the appropriate method for getting those values into a *tmux* session, but all of those environment variables should already be included in the default value of `update-environment`. The OP should check their `update-environment` value and possibly update wherever it is already being changed.

Comment: Hm..  after digging further, I agree -- the settings I listed are already in the defaults, and if I run tmux without a .tmux.conf file, everything works properly.  And if I remove the line I quoted from my .tmux.conf file, that is working for me as well, although it didn't before.  There's clearly something else going wrong occasionally.  Maybe to do with suspend/restore or attach/detach or sshing into a tmux session remotely.  I'll keep my eyes open and update if I find the factor which makes it reproducible.

Comment: `update-environment` is set correctly. However, the problem still occurs.

Comment: The problem with this is that config will only be re-executed when no `tmux` server is present, defying the purpose of re-attaching... Maybe there is a command line switch to re-update those variables?

Answer (score 3):

It happened to me that panes created when connecting via ssh from OS X started asking my passphrase after a while of working ok. I found a way to fix that stealing this line from http://santini.di.unimi.it/extras/ph/my-tmux-setup.html

```
eval $(tmux show-environment -t [YOUR-SESSION] | grep '^SSH_AUTH_SOCK')
```

Just run it from the pane that's complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are using bash or another shell, but [this guy's tmux setup](https://github.com/adnichols/tmux_setup) looks like it would work for bash. Personally, I am using zsh with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh), and I found that ssh-agent started working in tmux after I added

```
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent agent-forwarding on
```

to my .zshrc file and reloaded the config in my running zsh sessions. I also found [this guy's zsh-oriented solution](http://justinchouinard.com/blog/2010/04/10/fix-stale-ssh-environment-variables-in-gnu-screen-and-tmux/), but it turned out to be unnecessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

What does:

```
echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
echo $SSH_AGENT_PID
ssh-add -l
```

print?

Run it in your normal terminal, then run it inside your `tmux` session.  They should print the same thing.

Comment: I added the response to these commands to the question. I've also realised that the problem also occurs when I login over ssh (without using tmux), and have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: `ssh` is easy.  Turn agent forwarding on.  Easiest way to do that is run `ssh -A` instead of `ssh`. Use an alias so you don't have to type it every time, or put it in your `.SSH/config`.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That worked for ssh. Any ideas how to fix it in tmux?

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, but the simplest one is found in [Hans Ginzel's answer, dated 8 January 2016, to a related StackOverflow question dated 27 January 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34683596). Simply add the following to your shell `~/.profile` or similar:

```
alias ssh='eval $(tmux show-env -s | grep "^SSH_") && ssh'
```

There is no need to define multi-line functions or create new temporary files. If you don't want to alias `ssh`, simply change it to `fixssh` and remove `&& ssh` at the end, and run `fixssh` whenever you're trying to run `ssh` from inside a reattached tmux session.

The answer by Hans Ginzel suggests that a 'newer version' of tmux is required to run `show-env -s`. This works for me in tmux 2.7, and on my reading of the [changelog](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES), `-s` was added on 3 June 2008 just before the release of tmux 0.3. tmux 2.3 (29 September 2016) is in Debian stable.

Comment: fanatastic! Thanks!