# tmux: Cannot SSH from inside tmux, even though I have agent-forwarding (ssh -A) on

Tags: tmux, ssh-agent

So I have keys to some servers stored locally on my MacBook, but I work from inside a Virtual Machine a considerable amount of time, so I SSH to the VM with `ssh -A`.  This allows me to SSH to servers from inside the VM.

I recently started using tmux to manage my terminal windows better, but I've discovered an odd problem.  While the initial window I open in tmux can use SSH, any additional opened windows cannot.  `ssh-add` shows that from inside this tmux window no connection can be opened to my SSH agent.  Any ideas how to make tmux play nicely with SSH agent-forwarding?

Comment: Dup of http://superuser.com/q/237822/46794?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you open a second connection to your VM, it will use a different `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, but tmux and the processes under it will only know the old value.

When you attach to an existing session, tmux can tell the master process to update some environment variables. `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is already in the list, but you can add custom ones by `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -ga update-environment " FOO BAR"
```

However, this will only affect *new* tmux windows opened by <kbd>*prefix*</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>. It is impossible for tmux to update the environment of already running processes (shells, etc).

---

With OpenSSH you can reuse the *same* SSH connection for multiple sessions, retaining `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

1. Start a master connection:

   ```
   ssh -AfNMS ~/.ssh/myvmhostname.socket myvmhostname
   ```
2. Open a session over it:

   ```
   ssh -S ~/.ssh/myvmhostname.socket myvmhostname
   ```

(For automation of `-M` and `-S`, refer to `ControlMaster`/`ControlPath` in the `ssh_config` manual page.)

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know this is an old question,
But I found this [page](http://www.harry-b.de/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=harry:cpm) basically saing add this to your .bashrc file on your VM. Basically it links your ssh socket to a predicable target. TBH this may be a security issue, but I dont think it should be a huge one if you are the machine admin (I am no expert on security however):

(From marks blog)

In your .bashrc or .zshrc file, add the following:

```
# Predictable SSH authentication socket location.
SOCK="/tmp/ssh-agent-$USER-screen"
if test $SSH_AUTH_SOCK && [ $SSH_AUTH_SOCK != $SOCK ]
then
    ln -sf $SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SOCK
    export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SOCK
fi
```

Comment: To avoid the security problem, have the link in `~/tmp` rather than `/tmp`.