# how to identify the connected client pid/tty from inside tmux

Tags: ssh, terminal, tmux, ssh-agent

I'm using a long running tmux session on my workstation. Sometimes I have to connect to this workstation by ssh from my laptop. **I take my ssh private key stored on a YubiKey with me**. Means the Yubikey is connected to the Workstation **or** to the laptop. To use ssh inside of tmux I have to manage the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable to connect to the right ssh-agent.

for **new windows** I have already implemented the 'update-environment' solution I found [here](https://superuser.com/a/334986/1081764):

```bsh
set -ga update-environment "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

to **update the environment** of **already running sessions** I'm looking for any type of shortcut, alias or script.

**How can I identify a pid or the tty of the parrent session I'm currently connected to tmux** to select the right ssh-agent socked? Or is there a tmux command to update the "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" variable manual?

Answer (score 0):

With SSH_AUTH_SOCK in update-environment it will be changed in the session environment when you attach, so you can see it with "tmux showenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK" (note no -g because it is the session environment not the global environment that is changed by update-environment).

So you can look at that and use it to change the environment in any existing pane manually. If you are using a Bourne-style shell it should be as simple as "eval `tmux showenv -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK`".

Also note that SSH_AUTH_SOCK has been in the default update-environment since 2009 so you should not need to change it unless you are using a very very old tmux version.

Comment: This is a possible solution, but It has the problem that I have to disconnect and re-attach to tmux every time when I'm back at the workstation?!

Comment: If you don't want to do that you will need to  write your own script, you can use the client_tty format to get the ttyname outside tmux (or rather outside its best guess for the current client - IIRC it is the most recently used so should work for you).

Comment: thank you! Till I can identify the connected client I will use this workaround (including a re-attach):
```bash
alias sshclientSock='eval $(/usr/bin/tmux showenv -s SSH_AUTH_SOCK)'
```
Still looking for a solution to identify the current client...