# Is it possible to spawn an ssh-agent for a new tmux session?

Tags: ssh, tmux, ssh-agent

I've seen lots of hacks for re-establishing contact with a GUI session's SSH agent from within tmux (and screen) sessions. I'm wondering if it's possible to de-couple from the GUI and spawn an ssh-agent purely for use within a given tmux session? Would the agent itself have to "use-up" one of the tmux windows to avoid getting killed or is it possible to spawn one in the background that persists as long as the session is alive?

Comment: Dup of http://superuser.com/q/237822/46794?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I've done some more digging around and I should be able to easily hook to whatever SSH_AGENT is around when the terminal is attached. tmux already provides the key configuration "update-environment" however the missing piece is existing shells are not magically updated. However tmux does track the environment variables updated so the update script is a lot less hacky than screens:

```sh
# Sync the environment of an existing shell
#
#  tmux already updates the environment according to
#  the update-environment settings in the config. However
#  for existing shells you need to sync from from tmux's view
#  of the world.
function tmux_sync_env
{
    external_env=`tmux showenv | grep -v "^-"`
    export ${external_env}
}
```

From this [commit](https://github.com/stsquad/dotfiles/commit/a802d3705df486d5670644bdc2a79241e96141a9)

Comment: @Thor: I was wondering what was going on, I think the editor was inserting a space because the link was so long...

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify @stsquad's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/479840/199800). It was failing for me because the `export` command could not set the `SSH_CONNECTION` variable.

I had to wrap the value of `SSH_CONNECTION` in quotes.

```
function tmux_sync_env
{
    ssh_auth_sock=`tmux showenv | grep "^SSH_AUTH_SOCK"`
    ssh_connection=`tmux showenv | grep "^SSH_CONNECTION"`
    export ${ssh_auth_sock}
    export "${ssh_connection}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option I've found recently is Daniel Robbins' [keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) utility which offers a neat way to reconnect and have a user/host wide agent instead of just a session wide one.